# Error analysis of inverse tangent in sine

Tags: differentiation, error-analysis

I am trying to make an error analysis of the following function:

λ = d∙sin⁡(tan^(-1)(⁡y/a))

My assumption was that it would be as follows:

Δλ/λ= ∆d/d + (cos(1/(1+((y/a)*(∆y/y+∆a/a))^2))/(sin(tan^(-1)(y/a))

But the result is implausible. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that propagation of errors adds in quadrature, when the variables are independent. In this particular case, where $\lambda = f(d, y)$:
$$\begin{align}(\Delta \lambda)^2 &= \left(\Delta d \frac{\partial f}{\partial d} \right)^2 + \left(\Delta y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)^2\\
&=\left(\Delta d \sin \left[\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{a}\right]\right)^2 + \frac{(\Delta y)^2 a^4}{(y^2 + a^2)^3}.\end{align}$$

When $f$ is a function of many variables, $\mathbf{x}$, that have a non-diagonal covariance matrix, $\Sigma$, then the variance in $f$ is:
$$(\Delta f)^2 = (\nabla f)\cdot \Sigma \nabla f.$$

When $\mathbf{f}$ is a vector valued function (the number of components in $\mathbf{f}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are not necessarily the same) the covariance matrix of its components is:
$$\left[\Sigma_{\mathbf{f}}\right]_{i,j} = \sum_{n,m = 1}^{\operatorname{dim}\mathbf{x}} \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_n} [\Sigma_{\mathbf{x}}]_{n,m} \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial x_m}. $$ Notice how $\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_n}$ are the components of the [Jacobian matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Jacobian.html), pointing to a relationship between propagation of errors and changing variables in an integral.

Comment: I do not quite understand. Adjusting the formula for adding in quadrature would in my mind yield https://postimg.org/image/mrkbhcl8x/, although it is very possible that I am simply misunderstanding what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: Or maybe this https://postimg.org/image/em52rs4d1/ but both are incorrect anyway

Comment: I solved it now, in case anyone is interested: https://postimg.org/image/cj9cf7kph/

Comment: I skipped a few steps. You can simplify much of what you're attempting by the identity: $$\sin\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{a}\right)\right] = \frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2 + a^2}}.$$ The rest is a question of how terms are arranged (divide both sides of what I wrote by $\lambda^2$ to see). Regardless,  you're making more work for yourself by applying identities without understanding their origin. The origin is explained in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry but which part of your answer explains the aforementioned identity?

Comment: No part. The identity comes from the definition of the trig functions. Draw a right triangle and pick one of the non right angles. Label the side opposite that $y$ and the side adjacent $a$. Confirm that the $\mathrm{tangent}$ of the angle chosen is $y/a$. Construct the $\mathrm{sine}$ of the chosen angle using the triangle and, if needed, the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Ah, your comment made it sound otherwise so I got a bit confused. Thanks!